# Six-month post-doc on J-1 Research scholar visa, can one apply for another J-1 if physically departing before end of contract?

Tags: visa, united-states

Someone I know (nationality French) has accepted a six-month post-doctoral fellowship in the United States. The hosting institute will sponsor a J-1 visa; my understanding is that J-1 visas are much quicker to process than H-1B visas, and since she should start as soon as possible, they opt for J-1. A [J-1 Research Scholar visa](http://j1visa.state.gov/programs/professor-and-research-scholar/) has the following limitations:

> Professor and Research Scholars must:
>
> (...)
>
> Not have participated in a J-Visa program for all or part of the 12-month period immediately preceding the start date of a professor or research scholar program unless they meet one of the following exceptions:
>
> (...)
>
> The participant's prior physical presence in the U.S. on a J-visa program was less than six months in duration

If she *physically* leaves the United States one week before the end of her contract (having been in the US for 5 months, 3 weeks), for example to attend a conference in Europe or for working from home, can she still apply for a *new* post-doctoral fellowship (*NB: I'm not talking about an extension of the existing post-doc*) at a new J-1 research scholar visa, or will a H-1B visa be the only route still accessible for a new post-doc?

Comment: As a person who have gone through enough visa paperwork, I have to say that the **only** valid answer to that question is what the person in question will get from the non-immigrant visa department of the U.S. Embassy. Any other answer will most likely be irrelevant when/if it turns out that the embassy thinks different from whatever answer(s) you might get here (or anywhere else for that matter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yale University has a very nice [explanatory page](http://www.yale.edu/oiss/immigration/common/j1scholars/bar.html) for those 12 and 24-month rules, which are more complicated than the excerpts you quote:

[image]

This seems to contradict your quote. Note that it says specifically *“for any amount of time (one day to five years)”*.

Comment: Oh, right; I missed to quote an earlier part *Not have participated in and completed a professor or research scholar program within the last 24 months preceding the beginning date of their new program’s commencement*. I guess my quote relates to *J-1* visas that are *not* Research Scholar visas...

Comment: I have been in that situation with a short-term visiting scholar and I could get a new J-1 but I had to leave the country and apply for a new visa. Maybe it might have been possible to transfer the SEVIS fee to the new visa without paying it again.